# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\texmom\core\controller\Model.php on line 26

Tags: php

I'm tryinng to makes this work but.. I just tried everything... all is working fine but when i want to see the sells report by client it just throw me the message of the title. . . it's an inventory system. Help me!!

```
class Model {

    public static function exists($modelname){
        $fullpath = self::getFullpath($modelname);
        $found=false;
        if(file_exists($fullpath)){
            $found = true;
        }
        return $found;
    }

    public static function getFullpath($modelname){
        return Core::$root."core/app/model/".$modelname.".php";
    }

    public static function many($query,$aclass){
        $cnt = 0;
        $array = array();
        **while($r = $query->fetch_array()){** <-- **Line 26**
            $array[$cnt] = new $aclass;
            $cnt2=1;
            foreach ($r as $key => $v) {
                if($cnt2>0 && $cnt2%2==0){ 
                    $array[$cnt]->$key = $v;
                }
                $cnt2++;
            }
            $cnt++;
        }
        return $array;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////
    public static function one($query,$aclass){
        $cnt = 0;
        $found = null;
        $data = new $aclass;
        while($r = $query->fetch_array()){
            $cnt=1;
            foreach ($r as $key => $v) {
                if($cnt>0 && $cnt%2==0){ 
                    $data->$key = $v;
                }
                $cnt++;
            }

            $found = $data;
            break;
        }
        return $found;
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: Looks like your query threw an error and thus returned `false`. There are [library functions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to check for database errors.

Comment: You should check your query. Because your guery return false and you trying to fetch_array() on false. Thats is a boolean value.